# Issue on querydsl while trying to get Map from entity

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

My Entity class looks like this

```
public class EntityClass extends AbstractEntity {

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  targetClass=java.lang.String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "entity_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "p_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "propertyKey")
    @Column(name = "propertyValue")
    private Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

And Resource class like this

```
public class Response {

    private Map<String, String> properties
    @QueryProjection
    public Response (Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

}
```

Repository Imp class like this

```
public class EntityClassRepositoyImpl {

    public Response getReponse(Long id){

    QEntityClass entiryClass = QEntityClass.entityClass;

    return from(entiryClass)                 
           .where(entiryClass.id.eq(id)
           .uniqueResult(new QResponse(
                            entiryClass.properties
                    )); 
       }
    }
```

When the Repository method is called then it throws the exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: paymentRequestResponse near line 1, column 219 [select paymentRequestResponse.amount, paymentRequestResponse.narration, paymentRequestResponse.requestUniqueId, paymentRequestResponse.channel, paymentRequestResponse.transactionStatus, paymentRequestResponse.created, paymentRequestResponse.properties
>   from com.esewa.payment.log.PaymentRequestResponse paymentRequestResponse
>   where paymentRequestResponse.kernelEntryId = ?1 and paymentRequestResponse.accountId = ?2]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:129) ~[querydsl-jpa-3.7.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:311) ~[querydsl-jpa-3.7.1.jar:na]
>       at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractJPAQuery.java:304) ~[querydsl-jpa-3.7.1.jar:na]
>       at com.esewa.payment.log.PaymentRequestResponseRepositoryImpl.findByKernelEntryId(PaymentRequestResponseRepositoryImpl.java:83) ~[main/:na]
>       at com.esewa.payment.log.PaymentRequestResponseRepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1f16680.invoke() ~[main/:na]
>       at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 119 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: paymentRequestResponse near line 1, column 219 [select paymentRequestResponse.amount, paymentRequestResponse.narration, paymentRequestResponse.requestUniqueId, paymentRequestResponse.channel, paymentRequestResponse.transactionStatus, paymentRequestResponse.created, paymentRequestResponse.properties
>   from com.esewa.payment.log.PaymentRequestResponse paymentRequestResponse
>   where paymentRequestResponse.kernelEntryId = ?1 and paymentRequestResponse.accountId = ?2]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
>       ... 140 common frames omitted

Comment: i think this will not compile, missing return statement...

Comment: i forgot to write return statement before . It is                                                         return from(entiryClass)                 
       .where(entiryClass.id.eq(id)
       .uniqueResult(new QResponse(
                        entiryClass.properties
                )); 
   }

Comment: you could fix your code, it is confusing

Comment: it would help, if you enable debug log for querydsl (com.querydsl: trace) , and share the generated HQL with us.